# Docker блокирует подключения извне

Tags: linux, docker

Docker не дает подключиться к серверу извне, при запуске любого web приложения. 
Пример: запускаю teamcity в docker; запускается он по адресу `http://localhost:8111`; пытаюсь открыть приложение в браузере; браузер отвечает `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. 
Проблема появилась после переустановки ОС, с последующей установкой docker.

Comment: `$ docker run --rm -it -p 5555:5555 busybox sh -c 'echo netcat | nc -l -p 5555'`, в бразуере подключитесь к `http://localhost:5555`. видите строку «netcat»? // лучше, конечно, не в браузере, а в нормальном http-клиенте: `$ curl http://localhost:5555`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решило добавление параметров `--rm -it -p 8111:8111`